# Replace a column value with multiple values from another table - DB2

Tags: sql, db2, dashdb

I have a complex query ((Q1 union Q2) intersect (Q3 union Q4)). Now the issue is one of the column involved in the queries has the value of 'Company'. This value can be a particular company name or a value of 'ALL' which means all companies. I have a separate company table which lists the company names. Now the logic is if one of the query in intersect has a value of 'ALL' and the other query is company 'C1', the result should return 'C1'. But currently since 'ALL' does not match 'C1' as a string value the intersect does not return anything. 
Is there anyway I can replace the 'ALL' row value with all the company names and then do the intersect? I want to do all the operations through SQL because handling it in code will be very cumbersome. I am using DashDB which  is based on DB2.

Comment: Instead `intersect` use `INNER JOIN` - you need to join by all columns and the `company` column will looks like `AND (T1.[Company] = T2.[Company] OR T1.[Company] = 'ALL')`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try and let you know. But I have a confusion. Both the tables will have Company column. So which side to provide in select clause? T1.Company or T2. Company? I need the value of Company which is not 'ALL'? How do I know in which table it will be?

Comment: Thanks for the inner join and joining on 'ALL' criteria. The approach worked.

Comment: You can post your code and accepted your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query that solved my issue (I have removed complexities from the query and only included those portions related to this question)

```
SELECT 
AA.OBJECT_TYPE, 
AA.OBJECT_FILTER_ID, 
CASE WHEN BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL' 
  THEN AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE 
  ELSE BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE 
  END AS OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
    OBJECT_TYPE, 
    OBJECT_FILTER_ID, 
    OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE 
    from COMPANY
) AS AA 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT 
    OBJECT_TYPE ,
    OBJECT_FILTER_ID ,
    OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE 
    FROM DETAILS
) AS BB 
ON 
AA.OBJECT_TYPE = BB.OBJECT_TYPE AND 
AA.OBJECT_FILTER_ID = BB.OBJECT_FILTER_ID AND
(
AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE OR 
AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL' OR 
BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
select
    company_name
    ,the
    ,other
    ,columns
from 
(
    select distinct
        company_name = ca.company_name
        ,the
        ,other
        ,columns
    from Q1
        inner join companies_table ca
            on Q1.company_name = ca.company_name
            or Q1.company_name = 'ALL'

    union

    select distinct
        company_name = ca.company_name
        ,the
        ,other
        ,columns
    from Q2
        inner join companies_table ca
            on Q2.company_name = ca.company_name
            or Q2.company_name = 'ALL'
) a

intersect

select
    company_name
    ,the
    ,other
    ,columns
from 
(
    select distinct
        company_name = ca.company_name
        ,the
        ,other
        ,columns
    from Q3
        inner join companies_table ca
            on Q3.company_name = ca.company_name
            or Q3.company_name = 'ALL'

    union

    select distinct
        company_name = ca.company_name
        ,the
        ,other
        ,columns
    from Q4
        inner join companies_table ca
            on Q4.company_name = ca.company_name
            or Q4.company_name = 'ALL'
) b
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think cross apply works in SQL Server only. I am using DB2 here. Is there any alternative in DB2 for cross apply?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that DB2 doesn't support cross apply.
I have updated my answer with a solution that should also work, as it was suggested by gotqn.

Comment: This approach worked!! I had to modify the query a bit. Included some case when clause as well.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark it as answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> You can simplify your query like this:

```
SELECT AA.OBJECT_TYPE, AA.OBJECT_FILTER_ID, 
CASE WHEN BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL' THEN AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE ELSE BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE END AS OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE 
FROM COMPANY AS AA 
INNER JOIN DETAILS AS BB ON (AA.OBJECT_TYPE, AA.OBJECT_FILTER_ID)=(BB.OBJECT_TYPE, BB.OBJECT_FILTER_ID) 
AND(AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE OR AA.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL' OR BB.OBJECT_FILTER_VALUE = 'ALL')
```

Comment: This looks cool. Didn't knew of this syntax. Thanks for your suggestion.